# Get image width between given range with getElementbyClass javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i get the width of elements between a given range with jquery or javascript?

Let's say I have a buch of images hidden but I want to select only the ones that are big enough to matter to the client.

this is the code I am working on:

```
var imgLink = document.getElementsByClassName("imgLink")
array imgLk;
for (i=0;i<imgLink.length;i++) {
    if(imgLink[i].style.size >= "600px"){
        imgLk += imgLink[i];
    }
}

for (i=0;i<imgLk.length;i++) {
    if(imgLk[i].style.display == "none"){
        imgLk[i].style.display = "block";
        imgLk[i].style.opacity = "1";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `style.size` is a thing for images. Why not just `imgLink[i].width >= "600px"`? And it looks like you can combine it all in one `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I am trying to do actualy is to access the images in case a website doesn't have meta og:image, I get a bunch of them in display:none, then I want to get the bigger ones and in case it doesn't have any in that range go a range lower until I find some to display. So I was trying to use jquery width() but I can only remove what is less or bigger than x, one at a time, but I need to check if there are some first and then remove the rest.